# python string replace() method when replacing a character with surrounding spaces only replaces the first occurrence

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a string that I'm trying to replace when it has spaces surrounding the character like below:

```
>>> strvar = " a a b b "
>>> strvar.replace('a', 'r')
" r r b b " # WORKS!
>>> strvar.replace('a ', 'r ')
" r r b b " # WORKS!
>>> strvar.replace(' a', ' r')
" r r b b " # WORKS!
>>> strvar.replace(' a ', ' r ')
" r a b b " # only first occurrence is replaced
>>> strvar.replace(' b ', ' r ')
" a a r b " # only first occurrence is replaced
```

my question is that why can't python replace work on the last two situations??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you only have one instance of the string to be replaced. Lets break down your string:

```
" a a b b "
```

This is:

1. Space
2. `a`
3. Space
4. `a`
5. Space
6. `b`
7. Space
8. `b`
9. Space

When you ask to replace `' a '` it is looking for:

1. Space
2. `a`
3. Space

There is only one set of this (starting from left), hence only one substitution.

Answer (score 4):

Use a regex instead, as it will prevent issues caused by overlapping. See the following regex:

```
r'(?<= )a(?= )'
```

Replace with:

```
r
```

- `(?<= )` is a positive lookbehind group that asserts the match is following **" "**.
- `(?= )` is a positive lookahead group that asserts the match is followed by **" "**.

Comment: +1 That was a valid solution. Probably didn't get accepted because it didn't explain the OP's overlapping problem and how your regex addresses it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there is an overlap in the occurrences.

In the string: `" a a b b "`  There are no two occurrences of `" a "` because the spaces overlap. After the first occurrence is replaced the rest of the string is `"a b b"` which does not match your pattern

Answer (score 0):

it is not working because the sub-strings found are overlapping.
first occurrence found is ' a ', the rest of the string is 'a b b ', so of course it will not match ' a ' again